# How to Pass URL String in using Retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have class A which contains a variable. I need to pass the variable inside Class B interface file so, I can get Dynamic output in Kotlin. If Its a constant string then I am able to retrieve the result but I am not sure how to change the value on the fly.
 I used this below code for my Test but this is static JSON Value.

```
Class:A
        val intent= Intent(customView.context,ApiMovies::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(MOVIES_TITLE_KEY,Movies?.name)
Class:B
interface ApiMovies {
//   val name= intent.getStringExtra(MOVIES_TITLE_KEY,Movies?.name)

    @GET("get_movie.php?name=DunKirk")
    fun getMovies() : Observable<MovieResponse>
}

Class:C
        val retrofit : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://www.imdb.com")

Class:D
class MovieResponse {

    lateinit var data : List<Movie>
}
```

Comment: Retrofit doesn't use intents like that? I don't think your code can work. (`Intent` constructor you use is for components like an `Activity`) You have to use `retrofit.create(ApiMovies::class.java)` and call the `getMovies` method of the resulting automagic implemenentation of your `ApiMovies` interface. See e.g. https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890 - and if you want to make the name a variable use e.g. `@GET("get_movie.php") fun getMovies(@Query("name") name: String)` (or a query map but that's more flexibility than likely needed)

Comment: How to pass the  name variable if the intent doesnt work in Retrofit

Comment: fun getMovies(@Query("name") name: String):Observable<MovieResponse> Getting Error at getMovies       val apiMovies = retrofit.create(ApiMovies::class.java)
        println("Hello Api Movies: $apiMovies")
        apiMovies.getMovies()

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and put a more complete example of your code and especially the error you get? It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code without seeing all relevant parts. And also explain what want that `Intent` for. That part simply doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: please don't just refer to some github, your question should contain all parts relevant to answering it ([mcve]). There is also nothing in that github that uses intents like shown nor does it explain what *you* are trying to achieve. Your ` val name= intent.getStringExtra`  code probably needs to go in class `C` somewhere because if you look at retrofit examples like the official ones on https://square.github.io/retrofit/, you can see that you need to call the methods defined in the interface, parameters are not `val`s of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my code like below.

```
Class:A
        val intent= Intent(customView.context,ApiMovies::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(MOVIES_TITLE_KEY,Movies?.name)

 apiMovies.getMovies($intent)
Class:B
interface ApiMovies {

    @GET("get_movie.php")
    fun getMovies(@Query("name") name:String) : Observable<MovieResponse>
}

Class:C
        val retrofit : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://www.imdb.com")

Class:D
class MovieResponse {

    lateinit var data : List<Movie>
}
```

Comment: you can invoke api method directly in classA like following code:
apiMovies.getMovies(Movies?.name)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a params for your classB's method

```
Class:B interface ApiMovies { 
@GET("get_movie.php")
 fun getMovies(@QueryMap() Map<String, String> info) : Observable<MovieResponse>
 }
```

before invoking your method ,create a map,add k&v into map(map.add("name",xxx)),invoke it like getMovies(map),that will be ok,you needn't to pass your variable to classB.

Comment: thanks for your response but I am getting  fun getMovies(@QueryMap Map<String,String> info) : Observable<MovieResponse>  but I am getting parameter name expected before Map and A type annotation is required near on value parameter error at the end of the info

Comment: Still stuck in the same place.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why you must use intent to pass your variable?

Comment: why don't you invoke api method in classA?

Comment: Thanks for your help and I already did. Please check my answer.